# onUserLeaveHint gets called when entering activity

Tags: android

I'm creating an app that analyzes audio. When the user is about to leave the activity in which it's analyzing the audio, I want to create a dialog to ask whether the user wants to continue running the test or not. I'm using an on User Leave Hint to do this but it keeps getting called when I enter the activity from the main page as well. How can I fix this. Currently I'm only making a toast when the buttons are clicked.

```
@Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Continue running test?");
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast play = Toast.makeText(RecordAudio.this, "Continuing test", duration);
                play.show();
                finish();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                int duration2 = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast stop = Toast.makeText(RecordAudio.this, "Ending test", duration2);
                stop.show();
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because an Android device's HOME button (which invokes onUserLeaveHint()) is designed to **instantly** take the user to the device's desktop/home screen by force, hence why the dialog is still there when you reopen the app. That said, this is not good practice to confirm with the user before navigating out of the app to the home screen.

However, I'd recommend you use [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) (for the BACK button, obviously) instead when confirming with the user prior to exiting out of the app.

Comment: how does this answer the question? i dont get it. I have the the same issue of this method being called on activity launch

Comment: I am also facing the same, got any reolution?